# Failed to load module from user agent at localhost

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt

When I tried to run [GWT quick start tutorial](http://www.gwtproject.org/usingeclipse.html) I got this error message!

How can I fix this issue?

P.S.

1. I already installed GWT Developer plugin for Firefox 1.23
2. I installed eclipse from ubuntu 13.04 repository (version 3.8.1)
3. I already GWT from ubuntu 13.04 repository (version 2.4.0)

`00:27:29.230 [ERROR] [hellostupid] Failed to load module 'hellostupid' from user agent 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:23.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/23.0' at localhost:40544`

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.JsniChecker.getSuppressedWarnings(JsniChecker.java:565)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.JsniChecker$JsniDeclChecker.visit(JsniChecker.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeDeclaration.traverse(TypeDeclaration.java:1233)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.CompilationUnitDeclaration.traverse(CompilationUnitDeclaration.java:679)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.JsniChecker.check(JsniChecker.java:615)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.JsniChecker.check(JsniChecker.java:559)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationStateBuilder$CompileMoreLater$UnitProcessorImpl.process(CompilationStateBuilder.java:83)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.JdtCompiler$CompilerImpl.process(JdtCompiler.java:251)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:464)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.JdtCompiler.doCompile(JdtCompiler.java:710)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationStateBuilder$CompileMoreLater.compile(CompilationStateBuilder.java:235)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationStateBuilder.doBuildFrom(CompilationStateBuilder.java:447)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationStateBuilder.buildFrom(CompilationStateBuilder.java:370)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDef.getCompilationState(ModuleDef.java:360)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase$UiBrowserWidgetHostImpl.createModuleSpaceHost(DevModeBase.java:110)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.loadModule(OophmSessionHandler.java:197)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:525)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:363)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that eclipse gave me these two errors:  * `Description Resource Path Location Type
The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse. Fix the build path then try building this project HelloStupid  Unknown Java Problem`  * `Description Resource Path Location Type
The type javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files GreetingServiceImpl.java /HelloStupid/src/com/example/hello/server line 1 Java Problem`

Comment: It looks like you are missing jars in lib directory ( gwt-servlet ) and also might have not added gwt-dev.jar to the devmode launch classpath.

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean, all the steps I've done is:

1. apt-get install libgwt-dev-java libgwt-user-java eclipse eclipse-jdt ant
2. Successfully installed eclipse plugin after adding repository path http://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/4.2 
3. Added GWT path /usr/share/java thought Preferences -> Google -> Web Toolkit
4. Created the quick start tutorial then run it

So is there anything missing?!

Comment: Are you using GPE plugin to create the project. After creating the project please check whether the gwt-servlet.jar is in the WEB-INF/lib directory in the project.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue , you can try this if you are getting this problem -

1.[ERROR] [mysecondproj] - Unable to initialize static dispatcher

2.[ERROR] [mysecondproj] - Failed to load module 'mysecondproj' from user agent 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1712.2 Safari/537.36' at 127.0.0.1:63405

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29411048/gwt-starting-sample-project
```