# Gwt starting sample project

Tags: gwt

I am a beginer for gwt application when i am creating a sample application after all steps i am geting these errors in my Development mode window.

> 1.[ERROR] [mysecondproj] - Unable to initialize static dispatcher
>
> 2.[ERROR] [mysecondproj] - Failed to load module 'mysecondproj' from user agent 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36
>   (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1712.2 Safari/537.36' at
>   127.0.0.1:63405

And also in browser one message is coming like
3.Plugin failed to connect to Development Mode server at 127.0.0.1:9997.
I am using jdk 7,eclipse(luna),plugin version-4.3,sdk version-2.7.0and app engine version-1.9.18.so please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran into a similar problem, but I got errors that said

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.obectweb.asm.MethodVisitor.vistMetodInsn(ILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Z)V

This ended up being a buildpath problem. To fix it I did the following:

1. Right click on your package in `Eclipse>Build Path>Configure Build Path`
2. Go to the `Order and Export` Tab
3. Select GWT SDK and move it up above the App Engine SDK [`appengine-java-sdk`]

Comment: This seems to fix the problem, but **why** does it fix the problem?

Comment: thanks it helped me , i guess this is the reason -

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13942628/the-order-and-export-tab-in-java-build-path